# Why are there 2 different outputs

Tags: python, sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Qji.png)

The ouput was :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR,
        fullname VARCHAR,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

then when I run the second time, the output changed:

```
2019-04-18 21:07:17,156 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("users")

2019-04-18 21:07:17,157 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()

2019-04-18 21:07:17,161 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("addresses")

2019-04-18 21:07:17,166 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
```

Why there are changes here? Coung anyone explain for me?

Comment: Please read [why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and then edit your question.

Comment: How you make the blocks like that?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Shortcut: select some code and then press ctrl+k

Comment: I sometimes cannot use  that shortcut, when I marked some code and i press ctrl + k, there is a '?' on my search bar of my broswer. It do not make any blocks

Comment: @ViệtAnh, any line that starts with four spaces will be treated as a code block. I type my code in a normal editor, then highlight it all, tab, copy, and paste. I find it easier than dealing with the editor window shortcuts.

Comment: thank you my friend  @EricBrandt